# SD card communication failure with USB2244 and TS3A27518E

Tags: sd, analog-switch

I'm facing a very peculiar issue on a hobby project of mine, and would appreciate any insight.

The schematic for the relevant part of the project is attached at the end of this post. What I have is two microSD cards (`J1` and `J2` on the schematic) connected to a [USB2244](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2244) card reader (`U4`) via two analog switches: a [TS3A27518E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3a27518e.pdf) for the data lines (`U7`) and a [TS5A12301E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a12301e.pdf) for the power lines (`U5`). The design is based on the [evaluation board](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS50002298B-EVB-USB2240-IND_C-UsersManual-20140902.pdf) for the USB2244. The `CARD_SELECT` and `NCARD_DETECT` lines are connected to a microcontroller (not shown) and are used to select one of the cards and inform the reader that a card was inserted, respectively.

The problem I'm facing is that the card reader fails to establish communication with the card. I attached a logic analyzer to the card end (using a handy [sniffer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9419)), and after pulling the `NCARD_DETECT` line low I'm seeing the following pattern play out on the SD's `CMD` line:

1. The reader sends the `CMD0` command, AKA `GO_IDLE_STATE`. According to the [spec. I have access to](https://web.archive.org/web/20131205014133/https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/archive/part1_301.pdf), this should order the card enter an idle state.
2. After ~3ms the reader sends `CMD0` again.
3. After ~3ms the reader sends `CMD8` with the argument `0x1AA`, indicating that it supports voltages in the range 2.7-3.6V, and a check pattern of `0xAA`.
4. The card responds with a response type `R7`, and returns the same value of `0x1AA`.
5. Steps 1-4 are repeated.
6. The reader sends `CMD55` (`APP_CMD`), indicating that the next command is an "application-specific" command.
7. The card responds with `R1` and a value of `0x120`, which is interpreted as:

   - `CURRENT_STATE == Idle` (bits 12:9 are 0).
   - `READY_FOR_DATA`.
   - `APP_CMD`, i.e. the card expects an app command next.
8. The reader sends `CMD41`, with an argument of `0x40FF8000`, which is interpreted as:

   - The reader supports SDHC or SDXC (bit 30 is set).
   - The voltages supported by the reader are 2.7-3.6V (bits 23:8 are set).
9. The card responds with `R3` and a value of `0x00FF8000`, indicating that it supports the same voltages, but that it is busy (bit 31 is not set).
10. The reader sends `CMD55`.
11. The card **does not respond**.
12. After ~100ms, the process repeats from step 1.
13. The whole dance stops after ~1s, with the card reader powering down the card.

The voltage on the SD card stays at a pretty much constant ~2.9V during the whole process, with a momentary (~0.6us) dip to ~2.2V at step 9, where the card responds to `ACMD41`. *Note*: now that I'm writing this, could this dip be an issue, if the minimum voltage should be 2.7V? What in the circuit could be the cause?

I've ruled out the card and sniffer as an issue, as they work just fine with an actual card reader, as opposed to my contraption.

I've also recorded the voltages on the `CMD` and `CLK` lines, and the waves look pretty square to me:

[image: Logic analyzer digital and analog capture of two SD clock cycles, both showing square waves]

From looking at the Texas Instruments forums, it seems other people [also](https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/765358/ts3a27518e-ts3a27518-interfacing-with-sd-card) [had](https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/968015/ts3a27518e-can-t-access-sd-card) [issues](https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/979719/ts3a27518e-can-t-access-sd-emmc-card) with the TS3A27518E when using it to access SD cards. These other people talk about capacitance issues, so perhaps that's what I'm seeing? How can I diagnose this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Circuit schematic, showing two microSD card slots connected to a USB2244 card reader via a TS3A27518E analog switch for the data lines and a TS5A12301E switch for the power lines]